# Python- ARIMA predictions returning all NaNs

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, indexing, statsmodels, arima

I'm trying to follow the time series tutorial here (using my own dataset):

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/02/time-series-forecasting-methods/

Surprisingly, I am able to satisfactorily successfully reach Part 7: ARIMA. In this section, I am stumbling quite a bit. All the values in the Prediction column for it are NaN.

In the terminal, I see
`a date index has been provided but it has no associated frequency information and so will be ignored when forecasting`

My test data set has a few date gaps for when no transactions occurred, so I fill it with
`test=test.set_index('DATE').asfreq('D', fill_value=0)`
. I also do the same thing with my ARIMA dataset, so the index matches the test set.

The rest of the relevant code is as follows:

```
train=df[0:180]
test=df[180:]
SARIMA=test.copy()

fit=sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(train['COUNT'], order=(1,1,1), seasonal_order=(0,0,0,5)).fit()
SARIMA['SARIMA']=fit3.predict(start=0, 
    end=93,dynamic=True)

print(SARIMA) 
print(test)
```

In the print output, the index for the test set and ARIMA set are the same. The ARIMA contains a column `SARIMA` which contains the predictions, except they are all `NaN`. What am I missing?

```
test
DATE        COUNT
2018-06-21    1
2018-06-22    3
..
2018-11-21    3
2018-11-22    4

SARIMA
DATE        COUNT    SARIMA
2018-06-21    1       NaN
2018-06-22    3       NaN
..
2018-11-21    3       NaN
2018-11-22    4        NaN
```

edit:
for some reason `statsmodels` simply cannot detect the index frequency. I've tried
`SARIMA=SARIMA.set_index('DATE').asfreq('D',fill_value=0)`
`SARIMA.index=pd.to_datetime(SARIMA.index)`
`SARIM.index=pd.DatetimeIndex(SARIMA.index.values, freq='D')`
But the warning always appears

edit: I straight up tried to make a new dataset in Excel:

```
DATE       COUNT
2018/01/01   1
2018/01/02   2
..
2018/01/10   3
2018/01/11   4
```

created the model with the same lines above, except setting `enforce_stationarity` and `enforce invertibility` to `False`. All the predictions are still `NaN`

edit3: using the fake excel dataset, I've come 1 step closer. Passing `start='2018-01-01'` and `end='2018-01-21'` yielded predictions of all 0s, which is better than `NaN`. Can anyone make sense of these results?

edit4: setting `dynamic=False` returned reasonable predictions. Clearly I'm no statistican

Comment: Does the training or the test dataset have `Nan` values

Comment: running `df.isnull().values.any()` yields `False` so I don't think there are any `NaNs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another reason behind this behavior could be the 'sarimax' parameters. I have not found a way to overwrite it yet, so if this is the cause try changing your initial params.

```
import random
import statsmodels.api
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

endog = np.array(random.sample(range(100,200), 17))

for cd in range(2):

    m = statsmodels.api.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(
                                                    endog = endog,
                                                    order = (1,1,1),
                                                    seasonal_order = (0,cd,0,12),
                                                    trend = 'n'
                                               ).fit()


    plt.plot(endog)
    plt.plot(m.fittedvalues)
    plt.title('D: ' + str(cd))
    plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some dates were missing in the dataset
`SARIMA.index=pd.DatetimeIndex(SARIMA.index.values, freq='D')` corrected this.